# I am trying to install cabal-install on my Linux server

Tags: linux, haskell, ssh, cabal

It looks like most of the build is working but the actual install is failing.

A carefully place echo command reveals that this command is the one that is failing:

```
install_pkg "cabal-install"
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
cleaning...
Linking Setup ...
Configuring cabal-install-1.17.0...
Building cabal-install-1.17.0...
Preprocessing library cabal-install-1.17.0...
[ 1 of 71] Compiling Distribution.Compat.FilePerms ( Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.o )
[ 2 of 71] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Semaphore ( Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.o )

Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.hs:12:26:
    Module `Control.Exception' does not export `mask_'

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Building the cabal-install package failed
```

Here is the full transcript:

```
Checking installed packages for ghc-6.12.3...
Cabal is already installed and the version is ok.
transformers is already installed and the version is ok.
mtl is already installed and the version is ok.
deepseq is already installed and the version is ok.
text is already installed and the version is ok.
parsec is already installed and the version is ok.
network is already installed and the version is ok.
time is already installed and the version is ok.
HTTP is already installed and the version is ok.
zlib is already installed and the version is ok.
random is already installed and the version is ok.
stm is already installed and the version is ok.
===========================================
cleaning...
Linking Setup ...
Configuring cabal-install-1.17.0...
Building cabal-install-1.17.0...
Preprocessing library cabal-install-1.17.0...
[ 1 of 71] Compiling Distribution.Compat.FilePerms ( Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.o )
[ 2 of 71] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Semaphore ( Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.o )

Distribution/Compat/Semaphore.hs:12:26:
    Module `Control.Exception' does not export `mask_'

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Building the cabal-install package failed
```

Comment: Try an older version of cabal-install (e.g. 1.16).

Comment: I am trying to install on a Virtual Server and have decided it is just cheaper in time-money to have my provider do it for me. 

For the more intrepid, I found this great page:

http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/haskell-platform.xhtml